# SwiftyDropbox installation with CocoaPods - Dependency not used in concrete target

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, swiftydropbox

Xcode Version 7.3 (7D175)
SwiftyDropbox 3.0.0

I am following the installation instructions on https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/swift#install

1. Installed CocoaPods via

   $sudo gem install cocoapods
2. Not used Cocoapods before so run:

   $pod setup
3. Created "Podfile" in project directory and added the following text to the Podfile:

   `platform :ios, '8.0'`

   `use_frameworks!`

   `pod 'SwiftyDropbox'`
4. Closed xcode, navigated to project directory and executed install

   `$pod install`

Result

```
`[!] The dependency SwiftyDropbox is not used in any concrete target.`
```

Any suggestions, this is my first time using CocoaPods, which seems to be a pretty useful library.

Suspect this is something to do with CocoaPods not SwiftyDropbox.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Within the Podfile the following needs to be included.

`platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!
target 'foo' do
pod 'SwiftyDropbox'
end`